# Change time format Python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, strftime

Does anyone know how to use datetime function in python to transform my column in time format?
For some reason, I got a column like this:

| time |
| --- |
| 800 |
| 1430 |
| 1250 |
| 1020 |
| 407 |

I want them to be like this in datetime format:

| time |
| --- |
| 08:00 |
| 14:30 |
| 12:50 |
| 10:20 |
| 04:07 |

I cannot transform it with pd.to_datetime or strftime because python doesn't think they are in time format.

Answer (score 0):

Use `pd.to_datetime` and specify the format:

```
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'], format='%H%M').dt.strftime('%H:%M')
print(df)

# Output
    time
0  08:00
1  14:30
2  12:50
3  10:20
4  04:07
```

Another (messy) method to show you string manipulation with Pandas:

```
df['time'] = (df['time'].astype(str).str.pad(4, fillchar='0')
                        .replace(r'(\d{2})(\d{2})', r'\1:\2', regex=True))
```

Comment: I used pd.to_datetime and it showed unconverted data remains: 0. I will try another later.